# Reaction of chloroform, resorcinol and strong base

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, phenols

A common reaction used to identify resorcinol (benzene-1,3-diol) in the laboratory is to react it with chloroform in presence of 30% sodium hydroxide (NaOH). A red coloured solution (or precipitate) is produced. I have searched many books and websites, but none of them give any clue about the actual reaction, its products, far less the reaction mechanism.

The reaction is as follows:

$$\ce{Resorcinol + Chloroform + 30\% NaOH -> Red Colour}$$

So any ideas about what reaction is taking place?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-resorcinol-give-Iodoform-test#

Comment: @SoumikDas no, no, in this reaction, iodine or any other halogen is **not** added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Well, turns out to be, the reaction proceeds to product a **red colored species.**](http://intranet.tdmu.edu.ua/data/kafedra/internal/pharma_2/metod_rozrobky/en/pharm/prov_pharm/ptn/pharmaceutical%20chemistry/3%20course/11%20Pharmaceutical%20analysis%20of%20phenols,%20aromatic%20carboxylic%20acids%20and%20their%20salts.htm)

> **Reaction with chloroform in the alkaline medium**
>
> Dissolve 0.1 g in 1 ml of water R, add 1 ml of strong sodium hydroxide
>   solution R and 0.1 ml of chloroform R, heat and allow to cool. An
>   **intense, deep-red colour develops** which becomes pale yellow on the addition of a slight excess of hydrochloric acid R.
>
> [image]

Comment: @OscarLanzi probably. I could not find enough evidence to prove that.

Comment: Do you know the mechanism of this reaction? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You're probably looking at a two-part reaction.  First chloroform+sodium hydroxide imparts a carbonyl group ortho to a phenolic hydroxyl group ([see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichlorocarbene)).  Then this carbonyl group electrophilically attacks a second resorcinol molecule to give the dimeric structure.